# Error message regarding my input file using genepop package on R

Tags: r

I have a problem on R, I'm using genepop packages to calculate the Fst. Here is my script:
library(genepop)

```
setwd("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Test R")

infile<-file.choose()

Fst(
  infile,
  sizes = FALSE,
  pairs = T,
  outputFile = "Run0-Neu",
  dataType = "Diploid",
  verbose = interactive()
)`
```

But everytime I try I have this message error :

set_eof_check_EOLtype() cannot open file!

```
set_eof_check_EOLtype() cannot open file!
parseFile() cannot reopen C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Test although it could previously be 
opened.
Error in REstimatingSpatialStructureAlleleIdentyAllPopulationsPairs(inputFile,  : 
parseFile() cannot reopen input file.
```

I don't underrstand why because it's working on my lab computer it's working but not on my personal labtop and it's the same R version.

Is anyone ever encoutered this message error and have an idea on how I can solve this issue ?

Thank you.

Marie

Comment: What happens if you import the data with a `read` function, instead of using `file.choose()`? For example, `read.csv("file_name.csv")`

Comment: It didn't work either.
But I finally found solve the problem, it was because of the space in my file Test R, it didn't like it but without it everything fine ! 
Thank you.

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Does the `setwd()` command work on its own?

Comment: It was the first line 
    setwd("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Test R") 
it was working on it own that's why I didn't realize earlier
    setwd("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Test_R") solve the problem